# Given $|z|<1$ prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} z^n=0$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, complex-numbers

Given $|z|<1$ with $z \in \mathbb{C}$ prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} z^n=0$.

My attempt given $\epsilon >0$ we wish to show that there exists $\delta >0$ such that $n> \delta$ means $|z^n-0| < \epsilon$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have $|z^n|=|z|^n$. We wish $|z|^n < \epsilon$. This means,

$$n \ln |z| < \ln \epsilon$$

But because $\ln |z|<\ln 1=0$ dividing both sides by $\ln |z|$ gives:

$n> \frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln |z|}$

So that's what we choose for $\delta$.

My question is is how can we get away from the assumption that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Or is this correct even with the assumption?

Comment: When you write $\lim_{n\to \infty}$, it's usually implicit that $n$ is restricted to integers / natural numbers, just because it's $n$ instead of $x$ or $a$. It's not a good thing, really, but it is what it is. You can't be completely certain without reading the mind of whoever wrote it.

Comment: This proof is, however, not valid for $z=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that $z^n$ is multivalued when $n>0$ real is not an integer. The same argument though shows that whichever possibility you choose will still have absolute value approaching $0$. This misses the point, though; there's no reason to generalize to $n\notin \mathbb N$ for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.** Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{equation}
z^n=r^ne^{i n\theta}
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
|z^n|=|r^n||e^{i n\theta}|=r^n
\end{equation}
Now since $0 \leq|z|=r<1$, we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty}r^n=0.
\end{equation}
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. There exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|r^n|<\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

Thus
\begin{equation}
|z^n-0|=|r^n|<\epsilon
\end{equation}
for all $n \geq N$.
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty}z^n=0.~~~\blacksquare
\end{equation}